# Duplicating rows in Dataframe based on pattern in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several rows. When a pattern is found (say `;`, only found in the last column), I'd like to duplicate the row, but assign new value based on a column. All data are strings. For instance:

```
        A     B      C
 x1     b1a   kxl    Ak
 x2     b1b   txl    Ak
 x3     b1c   uxl    Ak;Lo  #should be duplicated
 x4     b1d   ixl    Lo
```

Becomes

```
        A     B      C
 x1     b1a   kxl    Ak
 x2     b1b   txl    Ak
 x3     b1c   uxl    Ak  #duplicated
 x3     b1c   uxl    Lo  #duplicated
 x4     b1d   ixl    Lo
```

I'm trying to get `groupby('C').split(';')` to work, but am not finding an efficient way to do it. How would you do it?

Of course, a quick and dirty way to do it is by running the DF row by row, but this is not very efficient I guess...

Comment: `;` are only in last column?

Comment: Thank you, another question is - all data are strings?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer. Yes, '; ' is only found in the last column. All data are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
s = df['C'].str.split(';')
df = df.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(df.index)), s.str.len())]
df['C'] = np.concatenate(s)
print (df)
      A    B   C
x1  b1a  kxl  Ak
x2  b1b  txl  Ak
x3  b1c  uxl  Ak
x3  b1c  uxl  Lo
x4  b1d  ixl  Lo
```

1. First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column by separator
2. For general solution [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) array created by [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) by length of `DataFrame` with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
3. Last replace column `C` by flattened values of splitted values